# How to create and fill a python matrix?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create a matrix by filling it with a formula, but an error constantly comes out "list index out of range"

Can you please tell me what [this error is?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXC3d.png)

```
import math
n=int(input("Enter the number of rows and columns: "))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        A[i][j]=(pow(10,math.log(i+1))/pow(10,math.log(j+2)))/(math.exp(math.log10(i+1.5))/math.exp(math.log10(j+0.5)))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(A[i][j],end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: after getting `n` from the user, you need to create a blank list of lists first: for instance, `A = [ [0] * n ] * n`

Comment: But check out matrices, or even just 2d arrays in numpy, that might be very useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you :

```
n = 3
A = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        A[i][j] = i+j
print(A)
# [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

I insist on `in range(n)` for initialization because you could have list copies that update at same time, which you do not want :

```
b = [[0]*n] * n
b[1][0] = 2
print(b)
# [[2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]
```